# spring ModelAndView issue - adding "html" prefix

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I have spring boot app:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Scope("prototype")
public class BillingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/testReport4_2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloReport(ModelMap modelMap, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        JRDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(payordMng.getPayordGrpAll(), true);
    modelMap.put("datasource", datasource);
    modelMap.put("format", "pdf");
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Blank_A4_2", modelMap);
    return modelAndView;
}
...
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

Security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test.html", "/home", "/chrglsk", "/chrgall").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();

        http
        .csrf().disable();
    }
```

My Report Blank_A4_2 firstly work fine, and it shows me Report.
I access it so: http://myserverIP/testReport4_2

But if I go to any static page, in my project, for example 
http://myserverIP/test.html and then if I visit back my report,
it won't show anything and I will see in java console next:

```
class path resource [Blank_A4_2.html.jasper] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Му report name in resource folder is Blank_A4_2.jasper, why spring boot adds
prefix "html" ?

Answer (score 0):

My question is similar this one [JasperReportsViewResolver add .html after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924436/jasperreportsviewresolver-add-html-after-some-time). And as suggested in it, I added 
produces = "application/pdf;charset=UTF-8"
like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testReport4_2", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf;charset=UTF-8")
```

to the controller method and this problem solved.